# Hyper-V server and SAS HBA

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I cannot find the option how to install SAS HBA (HP SC08Ge) into Hyper-V server to see the exported LUNs. Could you please help me in this matter ?

Comment: Is this a bare metal hyper-v 2008 R2 installation?  You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

(Old answer, when I misunderstood his question)

No such option exists.  Hyper-V supports the notion of passing a LUN through to the guest.  It does not support the notion of passing all LUNs from an HBA through to the guest.  (Nor all the LUNs on a specific target.)

(New answer now that I understand that you're talking about Hyper-V Server, not the VMs themselves.)

Go to the command line, find your driver package and type:

pnputil -a yoursashbadriver.inf

Reboot.

Comment: I do not need them in the guests :) But I see that there is some command how to install inf drivers in that evil command line..

Comment: @Mejmo - that "evil" command line will set you free. Give it an honest try sometime.